# Minimum number of moves For Numbering vertices of Cubes

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

N cubes placed side by side like the above picture. I have to Correct vertex numbering is shown in picture. From left to right, every face is numbered in counter-clockwise order. So first face has number 1-2-3-4, second face 5-6-7-8 and so on. So if N cubes are placed then, there are 4*(N+1) numbers (1 to 4N + 4).

Now initially the numbers are placed in random order. I have to make them correct order. To bring them in correct order, I can only swap 1 and an adjacent number of 1

[image]
For example, in the above diagram, we can swap (1, 8) and then (1, 5) to bring it into correct form.

Given, N-1(<=40) at input and number currently at 1, number currently at 2, … number currently at 4*N. I have to find out minimum number of moves

So if I have given the following input :

5 2 3 4 8 6 7 1

I have to output 2 .

I have tried several times to solve this problem but failed . Guyz , can you help me in this regard ?

Comment: You need $1,2,3,4$ to be in the leftmost plane in any order, then $5,6,7,8$ in the next one, and so on?

Comment: In your example, it looks like you should delete the first $8$ in the input.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a sliding block puzzle, like the [15 puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) or the [minus cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minus_Cube) (which is exactly the $N=1$ version of this question).  Think of the number $1$ as an empty space, which other numbers take turns filling.

Unfortunately for you, although algorithms to solve larger versions of the 15-puzzle are plentiful, finding the shortest solution is NP-hard, and this is likely to be the same.  I don't know about the minus cube, that one might be small enough to go through the entire search tree.

Comment: I'm not sure.  If the question is as I indicate in my comment to OP, it seems a greedy algorithm will work.  But I don't think we know yet what a solution is.